# Colours disappear after resort jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When css attributes are set during initialization it works fine, colours and backgrounds in cells also change when initiated from a function. But when I sort the columns all colours set from function disappear and go back to the normal grid.

```
<script>
var Mydata =[
  {
    "id":"560058",
    "nm" : "L 41971",
    "temp" : "21.2",
    "ignition" : "off",
    "pos_x" : "55.2024832",
    "pos_y" : "24.9640256",
    "drv" : "",
    "pos_s" : "0",
    "param24" : "0",
    "param240" : "0",
    "pwr_ext" : "12.825"
  },
  {
    "id":"560059",
    "nm" : "L 41972",
    "temp" : "21.2",
    "ignition" : "off",
    "pos_x" : "55.2024832",
    "pos_y" : "24.9640256",
    "drv" : "",
    "pos_s" : "0",
    "param24" : "0",
    "param240" : "0",
    "pwr_ext" : "12.825"
  }
];
var grid = $("#live_view");
grid.jqGrid({
  height: '100%',
  width: '700',
  datatype: "local",
  loadonce: true,
  data : Mydata,
  gridview: true,
  colNames: ['Name', 'Temperature', 'Ignition', 'lat', 'lon', 'Driver', 'Speed', 'param24', 'movement', 'pwr_ext'],
  colModel:[
    {name:'nm',index:'nm'},
    {name:'temp',index:'temp'},
    {name:'ignition',index:'ignition'},
    {name:'pos_x',index:'pos_x'},
    {name:'pos_y',index:'pos_y'},
    {name:'drv',index:'drv'},
    {name:'pos_s',index:'pos_s'},
    {name:'param24',index:'param24'},
    {name:'param240',index:'param240'},
    {name:'pwr_ext',index:'pwr_ext'},
  ],
  rowNum:100,
  rowList:[100,200,300],
  pager: '#pager2',
  sortname: 'param240',
  viewrecords: true,
  sortorder: "desc",
  caption:"Vertex Live View",
  loadComplete: function() {
    grid.jqGrid('setCell',"560058","nm","",color:'red'});
  },
});
$("#live_view").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
$("#cc").click(function (){
  $("#live_view").jqGrid('setCell',"560058","nm","",{color:'blue'});
})
</script>
<a href="#" id="cc">Change Colour</a>
```

Comment: not sure if its a typo or sumthing but check this line.. grid.jqGrid('setCell',"560058","nm","",color:'red'});

Answer (score 0):

When you sort, it recreates the html. For all jqgrid knows, the column you modified might not even be visible on the current page after sorting. Bottomline, you will need to reapply the colours.

You could peruse the jqGrid api, to see if they allow setting the colour of the cell from the model data. I don't think so though.